# Save data during Migration Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I want to save data during Migration. But after migration Database is empty. I Use next params for migration in my DBContext

```
Database.EnsureDeleted();
Database.EnsureCreated();
```

But after I have Database without data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [Create and Drop APIs documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created) you should not use `EnsureDeleted` / `EnsureCreated` when using Migrations, as `EnsureDeleted` will drop your database (and with it your data), and `EnsureCreated` will recreate it from scratch (schema only).
See the [Migrations documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/) for further information about creating migrations without loosing data.

Comment: when I do not use it I have next error:

There is already an object named 'Person' in the database.

Comment: Could you please add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show how you perform the migration?

Comment: I create migration 

PM> Add-Migration A_Few_field_Added3**************************

after that I Update

PM> Update-database A_Few_field_Added3******************

and after that I have error 

There is already an object named 'Person' in the database

Comment: Your database should be empty before applying the first migration.

Comment: should I create my Entity-classes and make first migration? After than to add some data to db, after that add some new fiend to entity and PM> Update-database ?

Comment: Yes! Just don't forget to call `Add-Migration` to actually create the migration before applying that migration using `Update-Database`.